# CTRL + Click Binding in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext

One very long standing habit I have with my IDE of many years is that the CTRL (or command) + Click selects a full word. It is the equivalent of doing a double click on a word currently in ST2. I am hoping to be able to restore this ability in ST2. Would I go about it with a key-binding or a plugin?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you create a `sublime-text-2/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap` file (assuming you are on Linux) and put this in it (If the file is already there then put it at the end of the file within the square brackets already present):

```
[
    {
        "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "press_args": {"by": "words"}
    }
]
```

It will override the standard Ctrl+Click behaviour, and do what you want. However the default Ctrl+Click behaviour is very cool - allowing for simultaneous multiple selections and cursors (try Ctrl+Clicking in different places in a file), so you may want to reassign that functionality elsewhere. If you wanted to change the multi-select feature to Ctrl+Alt+click, you can do this by also adding, inside the square brackets:

```
{
    "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["ctrl", "alt"],
    "press_command": "drag_select",
    "press_args": {"additive": true}
}
```

Comment: great answer. this worked. I agree that the multi-select behavior is cool. any idea how I could re-enable that using CTRL+ALT+Click?

Comment: @phirschybar - hey, thanks, added a little bit so you can reassign for this! :)

Comment: I wish I could give you more points. You are a ST2 hero. One note: The 'Alt' should be 'alt' (lowercase a). But this worked tip top. Thanks again.

Comment: Great Answer indeed. My double-click was disabled by default and didn't know what to do. Until it's annoying enough. And I found your answer. :)

Comment: Not working in OSX. Creating the file in sublime-text-2/Packages/User/Default (OSX).sublime-mousemap did not work.  I replaced the command directly into Packages/Default/Default (OSX).sublime-mousemap. I replaced "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["super"], with "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["super", "alt"], and works finally !    (i know this is not a pro solution, to overwrite the default files, but it's the only solution that I find so far )

Answer (score 7):

It Works for st3, i think works in st2

Linux - create "Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap" in ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User

Mac - create "Default (OSX).sublime-mousemap" in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User

Win - create "Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap" in %appdata%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User

```
[
    {
        "button": "button1", 
        "count": 1, 
        "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
        "press_command": "drag_select",
        "command": "goto_definition"
    }
]
```