# Can Sublime text 2 Follow path in a file?

Tags: php, editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is it possible to open a linked file in sublime text 2 ?
What I mean is, imagine I have the following code :

```
<?php

    require_once( 'include/const-inc.php' );
    require_once( 'include/db-inc.php' );
    require_once( 'classes/dummy-class.php' );

?>
```

I would love to be able to click on the files to open the corresponding file.
Sublime text knows the local file path so should be able to resolve the corresponding files paths no?

Comment: I remember a similar post. Take a look at this post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694823/ctrl-click-binding-in-sublime-text-2)

Comment: No this is not yet available.I think this is avilable in netbeans.

Comment: @Deepu actually, it is available. See below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Open-Include](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Open-Include) plugin, available via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net). It looks like it does exactly what you're looking for.